# Define transparent material in JSON Model format 3.1

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, webgl

I would like to ask, how to define transparent material in JSON Model format 3.1. I have tried following JSON but without any success:

```
 {
    "metadata": {
            "formatVersion" : 3 
    },
    "materials": [{
        "DbgColor" : 15658734,
        "DbgIndex" : 0,
        "DbgName" : "dummy",
        "illumination" : 2,
        "opticalDensity" : 0.5,
        "transparency" : 0.5,
        "colorAmbient" : [ 0.9, 0.1, 0.1 ],
        "colorDiffuse" : [ 0.1, 0.7, 0.1 ]
    }],
    "vertices": [0,0,0, 100,0,0, 100,100,0, 0,100,0 ],
    "normals": [],
    "colors": [1,0,0, 0,1,0 ],
    "uvs": [],
    "faces": [67, 0,1,2,3,0, 1]
}
```

I have also tried to play with different values for illumination, optical density and transparency, but also no luck.

Thanks Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `transparent: true` and `transparency: 0.5`. The latter maps to `opacity`.

```
"materials": [  {
    "DbgColor" : 15658734,
    "DbgIndex" : 0,
    "DbgName" : "dummy",
    "transparent" : true,
    "transparency" : 0.5,
    "colorAmbient" : [ 0.9, 0.1, 0.1 ],
    "colorDiffuse" : [ 0.1, 0.7, 0.1 ]
}],
```

three.js r.60